# Agora.io - How many simultaneous video call sessions are supported

Tags: agora.io

I want to develop an app where in you can video call and chat. But before i start to develop the app, I need to know how many simultaneous video call sessions are supported.

Example : User A and user B are video calling, so are users C and D, etc

Answer (score 0):

Agora supports unlimited number of video call sessions.